# Docker - all-spark-notebook - run from local volume - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, docker, pyspark

I have installed the **all-spark-notebook** docker image, but every time i run it, the container starts with any file but for the default empty work folder.

I use this command to run it:

```
sudo docker run -i -p 8888:8888 -v home/vaio/Documents/pyspark:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/pyspark-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

I prefer to use -i instead of -d but in any case the problem persist

I have another computer where I run the same command and it starts with the files of the selected local directory.

[image: Capture]

Comment: Are you just missing a `/` for the first `home/vaio`?

Comment: No, It was a test but it doesn't run without the first /

Comment: You said `the container starts with any file but for the default empty work folder.` I am not able to get the issue correctly. Can you show some screenshot explaining the issue?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3fxx.png

Comment: Your CSV is in the work folder, no?

Comment: Yes, my mistake was to create notebooks outside the work folder, indeed those files were erased at the moment of stopping the docker, I feel like the dumbest :( Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on ubuntu. The issue for me was with targeted hard drive name (showed as 'MyHDataStor1' in ubuntu file explorer but was actually 'MyHDataStor11'). Drag the targeted folder onto the terminal window to ensure correct folder mapping.